# C++: What script can I use to test my Apache and FastCGI set up?

Tags: c++, apache2, fastcgi, mod-fastcgi

I asked at serverfault: [How to set up apache with fastcgi and a simple test script?](https://serverfault.com/questions/175515/how-to-set-up-apache-with-fastcgi-and-a-simple-test-script) I have been having real difficulties for a couple of weeks trying to understand how to set up my machine so that I can test my C++ application with Apache/FastCGI.

I tried with the simplest "Hello World" type of script. The only reply I have had so far at serverfault suggested my test script couldn't possibly run with FastCGI and that I should ask here, at stackoverflow.

So: What is the simplest "Hello World" C++ script that I can test my Apache/FastCGI set up with?

And if you know what configuration I missed (see my question at severfault, linked above), please do tell me (here or there). Obviously, *that* is the real issue for me. The simple script is only so that I am sure that I am debugging my development server setup using something simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some examples of scripts on the [FastCGI website](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/examples/) .